# How to print 2 pages in 1 sheet in portrait

Tags: pdf, printing

Normally, when you want to print 2 pages per sheet in a pdf, you just have 2 options:

[image]

But I want to print the pages sitting side by side AND the sheet being in portrait mode, so like this:

[image]

The width of the pages of my document are less than half the width of a A4 sheet so there shouldn't be a problem with the dimension of the pages.

However, I can't find this option in Adobe reader or Chrome pdf reader, and re-editing the whole document with an app like Adobe Acrobat seems like to much work.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complete site for this type of work:
https://pdfresizer.com/multipage